# R knit to HTML and this is error Error: pandoc.exe:

Tags: r

I added a picture
[pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xf6': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RQFY.png)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your source file `thu.Rmd` is likely saved as something *other* than UTF-8. In RStudio, select "File" -> "Save with Encoding...", and in the dialogbox that pops up, select UTF-8. Close the file, re-open it, if necessary, try in RStudio "File" -> "Reopen with Encoding..", and again select UTF-8. Does everything look okay? Any weird characters? If not, then you can try to knit it.

Comment: I tried to save new file with "save with Encoding" in several type of code  UTF-8, ISO - 8859 - 1  but it still have same error notation. 

"pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xf6': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted" 

I am trying find other way to fix. If you any other suggest, plz let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Fortunately, I fixed problem, it is not relate to pandoc or type of code, I changed working directory of Rmardown to same file which I want to knit and it works.