# Shiny App to render Rmd with Flexdashboard Output Format shows pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a mini shiny based APP to render RMD file with FlexDashboard output format. However when I run the app during render process it shows below error

**pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xcf': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 1**

My Shiny App is below

```
 ui <- pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Shiny Render RMD"),
        sidebarPanel(
         shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
         shinyalert::useShinyalert(),
         actionButton("render", "Render RMD",icon=icon("play"),class="btn-success"),
         ),
        mainPanel(uiOutput("report"))
       )

     server <- function(session,input,output){  
       observeEvent(input$render, {
             output$report <- renderUI({
                includeHTML(
                   rmarkdown::render('mpg_ex.rmd',
                                     envir = new.env(),
                                     output_file=paste('RenderRMD_usingShiny_',
                                                       as.Date(data.table::as.IDate(Sys.Date())),'_',                                                           
                 strftime(Sys.time(),format="%I%M%S%p"),'.html', sep=""))
                 )
               
                })

             })
            }
          shinyApp(ui,server)
```

My mpg_ex.rmd file is as below

````
    ---
    title: "Render RMD"
    date: "`r format(Sys.Date(),'%d %B %Y')`"
    output: 
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: cosmo
    ---

   library(tidyquant)
   library(tidyverse)
   library(dplyr)

   ```{r, echo=FALSE}
   knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)
   ```

   ```{r}
    mpg_pivot_table_1 <- mpg%>%
    dplyr::group_by(manufacturer)%>%
    count(class, name = "n")%>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = class, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)%>%
   ungroup()

   mpg_long_summary_table <- mpg_pivot_table_1 %>%
   pivot_longer(
   cols      = compact:subcompact,
   names_to  = "class",
   values_to = "value")

    mpg_long_summary_table %>%
    ggplot(aes(class, manufacturer, fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_label(aes(label = value), fill = "white") +
    scale_fill_viridis_c() +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Class by Auto Manufacturer")
  ```
````

If I change the output in my RMD file to html_output it renders without pandoc error. Any suggestions on what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66387092/10992158)

> "File" -> "Save with Encoding...", and in the dialogbox that pops up, select UTF-8. Close the file, re-open it, if necessary, try in RStudio "File" -> "Reopen with Encoding..", and again select UTF-8.

As this may be due to an encoding error, where maybe a single character is causing the issue. Maybe even try copying the file as a new file to see if that removes the encoding error.

Another suggestion is to make sure your current working directory is the directory you want to knit from. Is your Shiny app and Rmd file in the same Directory? If not, try running the app with the .Rmd in the same directory.

Also in your Rmd, you have

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
```

and I think those should be inside the R chunks, correct?

This ran fine for me, as an `html_document`

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel, Yes loading library should be inside R chunks. However I already tried that suggestion from SO answer before posting my issue. In YAML header if output format is set to flexdashbaord I see pandoc error is thrown. If set to any other output i.e, html_document I didn't see this issue. I need to render flexdashboard output file ultimately as my final application has many tabs with plots, tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find the cause of my issue.

Apparently `strftime(Sys.time(),format="%I%M%S%p")` yielded some foreign character e.g "043701下午"(some settings in my PC is in Chinese).

I modified my code to use `strftime(Sys.time(),format="%H%M%S")` which fixed my pandoc issue and it has nothing to do with output format in YAML header.